# What does "moveToLocal: Option '-moveToLocal' is not implemented yet." means?

Tags: bash, hadoop, hdfs, hadoop2, oozie-workflow

I'm running a oozie workflow with some bash scripts in a hadoop environment (Hadoop 2.7.3). but my workflow is failing because my shell action get an error. After save the commands output in a file as a log I found in it the next entry:

```
 moveToLocal: Option '-moveToLocal' is not implemented yet.
```

After I get this error my shell action fails becouse it takes this as an error and fails the entire action?

Also that line means that my current version of hadoop (2.7.3) doesn't support that command?

Comment: I got it. according to the documentation for my hadoop version: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.3/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#moveToLocal it says is not support it yet. so my a

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation for 2.7.3 hadoop version:

```
 https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.3/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#moveToLocal
```

Says this command is not support it yet. Now, my shell action take it as an exception and terminate the shell script. I'm changing that command for an equivalent.